# System.IntPtr and nint in C# Microsoft.CodeAnalysis

Tags: c#, code-analysis, intptr, microsoft.codeanalysis, sourcegenerators

In a normal comparison of types
`typeof(nint)==typeof(System.IntPtr)` is true

so I was expecting that the `SpecialType` of `System.IntPtr` is `nint`, just like `System.Int32` and `int`, when doing CodeAnalysis using `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis`.

but it turns out the SpecialType of System.IntPtr is still System.IntPtr.

here's my code

```
string GetSpecialTypeForDisplayIfAny(ISymbol symbol)
{
   return symbol.ToDisplayString(SymbolDisplayFormat.FullyQualifiedFormat
            .WithGlobalNamespaceStyle(SymbolDisplayGlobalNamespaceStyle.Omitted)
            .AddMiscellaneousOptions(SymbolDisplayMiscellaneousOptions.IncludeNullableReferenceTypeModifier)
            .AddMiscellaneousOptions(SymbolDisplayMiscellaneousOptions.UseSpecialTypes)
            .AddMiscellaneousOptions(SymbolDisplayMiscellaneousOptions.IncludeNullableReferenceTypeModifier)
            .AddMiscellaneousOptions(SymbolDisplayMiscellaneousOptions.IncludeNotNullableReferenceTypeModifier))
);
}
```

So my question is why is the SpecialType of `System.IntPtr` not `nint` in CodeAnalysis?

PS. I've already gone through this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nint-nuint). I understand that *".. the keywords are not simply aliases for the types."* but why is this true then `typeof(nint)==typeof(System.IntPtr)`?

Comment: `nint` is a C# v9 keyword that maps to IntPtr, the type that the runtime understands.  Just like `int` maps to Int32 and `string` to String, etc.  It is indeed not a simple alias like int, they removed the dangerous members like ToInt32(), ToPointer(), etc.  Having code analysis represent it in SpecialType is sensible, except that it takes an act of God to modify [the core types](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/main/docs/compilers/Co-located%20core%20types.md).  You can ask Him at github, but odds are not good.

Comment: That's just sad, so I guess the best I can do now is to just manually replace 'System.IntPtr' and 'System.UIntPtr' using 'Replace("System.IntPtr", "nint").Replace("System.UIntPtr", "nuint")'?